# Getting a 404 after starting Artifactory/Tomcat running on centos

Tags: tomcat, centos, artifactory

I'm trying to get Artifactory running on a centos server. This is what I did:

Created a new user called artifactory

switched to that user

`wget https://bintray.com/artifact/download/jfrog/artifactory-rpms/jfrog-artifactory-oss-4.0.2.rpm`

then followed instructions from artifactorys docs

`rpm -ivh jfrog-artifactory-oss-4.0.2.rpm`

`service artifactory start`

`service artifactory check`

I get a pid, which according to docs. Everything is working properly. I then navigate to the webpage, but I get a 404:

> HTTP Status 404 - /artifactory
>
> type Status report
>
> message /artifactory
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.0.22

I want to check logs, which are apparently located at $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/artifactory.log but dir is not found. Doing echo $ARTIFACTORY_HOME doesn't output anything. I did a find command on artifactory.log but no results. Super confused. Any tips would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Here are some log updates as per the tips from JBaruch.

I navigated to /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/logs

ls showed `catalina.2015-09-04.log  catalina.out  host-manager.2015-09-04.log  localhost.2015-09-04.log  manager.2015-09-04.log`

Here is a output from catalina.out and from localhost.2015-09-04.log:

catalina.out

```
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8019"]
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.22
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/artifactory] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
WARNING: The web application [artifactory] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml has finished in 2,004 ms
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 57 ms
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Sep 04, 2015 1:26:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8019"]
```

And for localhost.2015-09-04.log

```
04-Sep-2015 13:26:32.596 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener
 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/artifactory/webapp/servlet/ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2476)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1750)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

04-Sep-2015 13:26:32.598 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.logback.LogbackConfigListener
 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/artifactory/webapp/servlet/logback/LogbackConfigListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.logback.LogbackConfigListener)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2476)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1750)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

04-Sep-2015 13:26:32.600 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener
 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/artifactory/webapp/servlet/ArtifactoryContextConfigListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2476)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1750)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

04-Sep-2015 13:26:32.607 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

Comment: It fails before Artifactory logging starts. Check Tomcat logs, namely catalina.out and localhost.log

Comment: @JBaruch in /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat, catalina.out has a line `SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file`. Actually I'll update my main question with details. At this point, I'm not sure if it would be better to create a new question or update this one, but since you are an artifactory DA, I'm sure you'll be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: localhost.log should have the details then. That's the "container log".

Comment: @JBaruch Updated my question. I don't have a localhost.log, just a localhost.2015-09-04.log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Artifactory 4 supports Java version 8 and up.

Comment: Hmm... I my JAVA_HOME is set openJDK 8. I guess I have a java 7 runtime set somewhere on my system?

Comment: @JBarush I ran `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and saw 7 listed and 8. I selected jdk 8. Everything is running smoothly. Two more things if you could potentially answer for me. 1. Is $ARTIFACTORY_HOME supposed to be created by the rpm because doing echo $ARTIFACTORY_HOME shows nothing. 2. Is there any concern for me because I created an artifactory user first on my machine before I installed from rpm?